# The method getFirst() is undefined for the type Queue<Vertex>

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, queue

```
@Override
public Vertex next() {
   Queue<Vertex> nV = new LinkedList<Vertex>(graph.getNeighbours(this.sV));
   System.out.println(nV.getFirst());
   return nV.getFirst();
}
```

Above I declare a queue `nV` which is a queue instantiated by a Linked List. A LinkedList type should have the method `getFirst()`, why won't this program allow it?? I'm ok with even using a `pop` since it's a queue if this is possible but not sure if that works either.

```
ERROR at solution.java (at line 42)
return nV.getFirst();
          ^^^^^^^^
The method getFirst() is undefined for the type Queue<Vertex>
```

Comment: But you've got a reference to a `Queue`, not a `LinkedList`. Change `nV` to a `LinkedList<Vertex>` if you want to use methods specific to `LinkedList`.

Comment: Do you see a `getFirst` here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html?

Comment: @Tunaki please read my question and try understand my confusion, I know a queue doesn't have a damn getFirst method, I'm in confusion with the types as I instantiate it as Linkedlist so thought it should have access to that type. I guess i'll try the first comments suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method you're looking for is the `peek` method. The `peek` method returns the first element of the queue without removing it from the queue. However, if you do wish to remove the first element from the queue, then use the `remove` method, which dequeues an element from the queue.

Change `nV.getFirst()` to either `nV.peek()` or `nV.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the LinkedList instance to a pointer of type Queue, that does not expose the getFirst() method, try with this:

```
@Override
public Vertex next() {
 LinkedList<Vertex> nV = new LinkedList<Vertex>(graph.getNeighbours(this.sV));
 System.out.println(nV.getFirst());
 return nV.getFirst();
}
```

The LinkedList class implements the Queue interface, but the the getFirst() method is Inherited from the Deque, in fact, you could also do

```
Deque nV = new LinkedList<Vertex>(graph.getNeighbours(this.sV));
```

To have available the getFirst() method